# Display images in Neo4J brower using file name property

Tags: neo4j

How could i display the image.jpg corresponding to a node by clicking on the name of the file (property of the node) in the Neo4j CE 3.2.6 browser. The file being stored locally or on a server? Is there any simple alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j browser does not support clickable links directly.

However, your browser may have that ability built in, or it may have a plugin that can do that. For this to work, your image links would have to be complete URLs, though.

For example, the Chrome browser has a [Text Url Linker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-url-linker/aegfbpchoheaflicfmggkmlmcccpjpgd) extension that can turn `http` URL strings into clickable links. (That extension does not support `file` URLs, but there may be other extensions that do.) To see the image, you would select the node of interest in the neo4j browser, and click on the URL value for that node in the bottom of the current pane. You can also right-click on the URL if you want to use the `Open Link in New Tab` option.